# High fever during suhoor which led me to miss it. Feeling better next day

Tags: sawm, ramadan, sick

Yesterday, I had high fever and was unable to do suhoor and planned to miss the fast. However, I still made the niyyah for the fast hoping my condition will get better the next day. I woke up at 8 and although my fever is way more manageable, My throat is extremely dry and I fear it will get sore and my cough would get worse with it. I still feel I'll be able to manage if I really try and that a sore throat and cough is not as big of a deal for me to lead me to breaking my fast and IF it gets alot worse I'll only then break my fast.